# Ordering and grouping records together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a query which returns parent and child records. Each record will have a total amount field. I'm attempting to sort the query by total amount but on a parent level. The child records will appear immediately below the parent

So for example, if I have the following

```
| RecordID | Parent   |    Total |

|123       |         1|       90 |

|235       |         0|       70 |

|123       |         0|      100 |

|235       |         1|       60 |
```

And i sort highest to lowest, it should look like this

```
RecordID    Parent    Total

| 123           | 1 |          90 |

| 123           | 0 |         100 |

| 235           | 1 |          60 |

| 235           | 0 |          70 |
```

I'm thinking that I might need to put some sort of sortnumber in the select query for each group, so i this example, `RecordID` 123 would be assigned 1, and record 235 would be assigned 2.

Using this, I could then Sort by `SortNumber`, `Parent`, `Total`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple self JOIN to get the parent value should do it well;

```
SELECT a.*
FROM mytable a
JOIN mytable b
  ON a.recordid=b.recordid
 AND b.parent=1
ORDER BY b.total,b.recordid,a.parent DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39bde3/2).

Comment: This is what I had said in my initial post and something which I just implemented just before you replied. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with sorting by `recordid`?

```
select recordid, parent, total
from yourtable
order by recordid, parent desc, total
```

Comment: I need to sort the total amount on a parent level. So for example, Parent 123 has the highest then parent 235. There is no relation between record id and the total amount.

Comment: If you need to sort the "total amount", then you should show that in your example output. The `ORDER BY` in the answer seems to match your example output exactly. You might also need to show your table definitions since your comment about `record id` doesn't seem to make sense. (If there's "no relation", how do you expect them to show in the same rows in the result set?) Your example output seems to contradict your written description.